# Select distinct multiple columns with MAX value from father table

Tags: sql, oracle

**Table GAMES**

| gameId | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 452 |
| 2 | Tom | 453 |

**Table GAME_DETAILS**

| gameDetailIds | gameId | posX | posY | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | -1 | -1 | 1665264019 |
| 2 | 1 | -1 | 0 | 1665264020 |
| 3 | 1 | -1 | 1 | 1665264021 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 1665264022 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1665264023 |
| 6 | 2 | -1 | -1 | 1665264024 |
| 7 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 1665264025 |
| 8 | 2 | -1 | 1 | 1665264026 |

I want to find all of Tom's **posX** and **posY** where **posX** and **posY** are unique and it belongs to the game with the highest **score**

| gameDetailIds | gameId | posX | posY | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 1665264022 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1665264023 |
| 6 | 2 | -1 | -1 | 1665264024 |
| 7 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 1665264025 |
| 8 | 2 | -1 | 1 | 1665264026 |

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why is gameid 1 in your results? It is not the game with the highes score.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I want to find Tom's results. [-1;-1], [-1;0], [-1;1] is the highest score (game 2) , [0;-1] [0;0] is the position with the highest score ( games 1).
i want distinct result of posX and posY

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good. If something is confusing, I will try to make it clear

Comment: Yes, that's hard to understand. I suppose: You want to show all rows of the game with the highest points. Then, of the second highest points game you want to show all positions that are not in the highest game. Then, of the third highest you show all positions that don't exist in the two highest. And so on. Yes?

Comment: Yes exactly @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to show all distinct postions, but per position you want to show the "best" row. "Best" means the game with the highest score for that position.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to mark these best rows with #1. Then keep only those rows.

```
select gamedetailids, gameid, posx, posy, time
from
(
  select
    gameid, gd.gamedetailids, gd.posx, gd.posy, gd.time,
    row_number() over (partition by gd.posx, gd.posy order by g.score desc, gd.time) as rn
  from game_details gd
  join game g using (gameid)
  where g.name = 'Tom'
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by posx, posy;
```